# Change location of buttons at execution VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button, position

I am trying to change the location and size of buttons I have contained in a panel on a WinForm (vb.NET).
Initially the buttons have a location and an image (no text), but in execution I want to set a new location and text.
I am able to set the text for each button, and as they are set to Autosize, they increase in width.
But despite I set the location by code correctly, when the buttons are displayed they "come back" to their initial position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

IM

Comment: Please tell us a little more about what you're doing.  Show us your code.  Are you changing the location and size in the constructor?  In the load event handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will change the location to the co-ordinates you specify:

```
Button1.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

You must change the x,y values to the co-ordinates on the form that you want to move the button too.

The next bit of code with change the size of your button:

```
Button1.Height = 10
Button1.Width = 50
```

Comment: Hi,

I have solved the issue. I had to do the location of the buttons on the ClientSizeChanged event of my form.

Thanks for your interest anyway.

IM